# Determine if input contains arithmetic operators in c

Tags: c

I want to loop through the characters in my array arithchar to determine if any character entered matches it.

My code looks like:

```
 int checkForAO(char password_entered[]);
 int main(){
    if(checkForAO(password_entered)){
        //contains a password with ao
    }
    else{
        //doesnt contain special ao.
    }

    int checkForAO(char password_entered[]){
        int i;
        char arithchar[4] = {'+','-','*','/'};
        for (i=0; i<strlen(password_entered); i++) {
            if ( <<<< password_entered[i] contains any character in arithchar array  >>>>>>> ) ) {
                printf("\nYour password contain(s) ao.\n");
                return true;
            }
        }
        printf("\nYour password didn't contain any ao.\n");
        return false;
    }
```

I need help especially on determining my final `if{}` statement, i tried pseudocoding out what I needed, but can't seem to figure this one out.

Thank you.

Comment: Try a `for` statement instead of that `if{}` statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [strpbrk](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strpbrk) in `<string.h>`

E.g

```
int checkForAO(char password_entered[]){
    if(strpbrk(password_entered, "+-*/")){
        printf("\nYour password contain(s) ao.\n");
        return true;
    } else {
        printf("\nYour password didn't contain any ao.\n");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest you to do is add following line in if :

```
if ( password_entered[i] == '+' || password_entered[i] == '-' || password_entered[i] == '*' || password_entered[i] == '/') )
```

and remove following line :

```
// char arithchar[4] = {'+','-','*','/'};
```

Your function will become like :

```
 int checkForAO(char password_entered[]){
    int i;

    // char arithchar[4] = {'+','-','*','/'};
    for (i=0; i<strlen(password_entered); i++) {
        if ( password_entered[i] == '+' || password_entered[i] == '-' || password_entered[i] == '*' || password_entered[i] == '/') )
        {
            printf("\nYour password contain(s) ao.\n");
            return true;
        }
    }
    printf("\nYour password didn't contain any ao.\n");
    return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (i=0; i<strlen(password_entered); i++) 
{
                    for(int j=0;j<strlen(arithchar);j++)
     {
              if(password_entered[i]==arithchar[j])
               {
                        printf("\nYour password contain(s) ao.\n");
                        return true;
               }
     }
}
```

would work.

Answer (score 0):

A compact solution, using `strchr()`:

```
int checkForAO(char password_entered[])
{
    for (i=0; i<strlen(password_entered); i++)
    {
        if (strchr("+-*/", password_entered[i]) != NULL)
        {
            printf("\nYour password contain(s) ao.\n");
            return true;
        }
    }
    printf("\nYour password didn't contain any ao.\n");
    return false;
}
```

Note that the use of `strchr()` makes it able to be extended quite easily.